# how to place two components side by side inside same html.Div()?

Tags: plotly-dash

I place dbc.Label() and dcc.RadioItems() inside one html.Div() and I'd like to place these Label and RadioItems() side by side.

I did below and it didn't work, dbc.Label and dcc.RadioItems are on different rows. Thanks for help.

```
        crossplot_radio_items = html.Div(
            [
            dbc.Label('Choose Pads',style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
            dbc.RadioItems(
            options=[
                {"label": "AllPads", "value": "AllPads"},
                {"label": "Pad74", "value": "74"},
                {"label": "Pad75", "value": "75"},
                {"label": "Pad77", "value": "77"},
                {"label": "Pad78", "value": "78"},
            ],
            value="AllPads",  
            id="conformance-crossplot-radio-items",
            labelCheckedClassName="label-radio-checked",
            inputClassName="label-radio-input",
            inline=True,
                        ),
            style={'display': 'inline-block'}
            ],
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe doing something like: `style={'display': 'flex', 'flex-direction', 'column' }` can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style goes outside children..

children=[],
style={'display': 'flex'}

Comment: Thanks Berg, yes, it works, also if I place style inside children, I need to use margin-left=10 to get it work. so what does flex mean? can you say it again? Thanks

Comment: There's probably a style property for the RadioItems as well but if you want objects in a Div to be side by side then you have to declare that in the Div.  I'm not an expert Dash guy but I've never had the 'inline-block' work for me in a Div.  Maybe it's deprecated?   Anyway, most of the styling in Dash is just plain old CSS. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/